# Is there any way to get keycode in asp.net without use of JavaScript and Jquery?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to develop MACRO operation in asp.net and for that i want to get "keycode" of pressed key during defined session. Here, i want to programmed only in asp.net class file, don't want to use j Query , JavaScript, or any else.  Can any one help me to programmed only in asp.net class file?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get a key pressed using only ASP.NET with the exception of capturing a key pressed on a certain control.

You could use the OnKeyPress event of an asp:TextBox but to get the keypress you would need to have the TextBox focused. This uses JavaScript on the generated page which is used to send the event to be handled to a method on the server. So even though you would not be writing any JavaScript, it would be generated automatically since it is needed for the page to work as intended.

The other way is to capture a key press with JavaScript manually and send it to be handled by a method on the server.

Check the post by Programming Hero to see a way it can be done using JavaScript and jQuery:

[Catching keypress in ASP.NET textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346045/catching-keypress-in-asp-net-textbox)